# Why are foreign keys stored in child items rather than parent items in a database

Tags: database, oop

I feel like there is probably a sensible answer to this question. When I create child objects in code, the parent object stores a reference to the child. The children don't know about the parent unless there is a specific reason for them to store a reference.

With databases, the opposite is the norm. ie: You create something that "has many" something elses, and a reference to the parent is stored in each of the many child items.

So generally speaking if I am programming, I have a list of child items stored in the parent. If I am databasing, I have many child items each with a parent-reference, but the parents do not have references to the children.

How and why did this come to pass? Is it just a matter of arbitrary design decisions becoming the norm, or is there a performance or logic reason behind data stores doing it one way and code objects doing it another?

Comment: In theory you COULD create an array value in a field listing all child IDs, but that's terribly inefficient and SQL based databases aren't built to work that way.

Comment: @Logarr I figured... similarly I could create child objects in oop and mark them as children by storing references to a "blind" parent... but I don't think anyone does that much (unless maybe they are programming a new database? ;) ). It makes me wonder why two domains of programming that interface with each other are organized in opposite ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if that's quite the real reason, but here's my view.

The fundamental difference I find is that, in databases, each cell is designed to contain one, and only one piece of data. The child can easily reference the parent though its PK, effectively forming a FK there. But, how would the parent reference the childs?

Remember that in a one-to-many relationship, each parent may have an arbitrary number of childs, so what kind of column would the parent need to hold those references? Having the PK of the child would be useless, since you can hold only one per column (that would make a one-to-one instead). You can't simply put a list of PKs in a DB cell, except though hacks like a comma-separated string, but that would defeat the purpose of FK and eliminate most benefits of RMDBS. An intermediate table is a possible solution, but then you're just moving the problem to another place, as that table then becomes the child, and the parent still has no references to it.

In contrast, OOP languages contain data structures that can be used to store multiple items in a single property: **collections**. With those you have a property that contains an object containing multiple, arbitrary number of child object references. Is this kind of structure what relational databases lack to make such a reference possible. Child to parent reference (or a many-to-one side) is also possible with a normal object reference.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I can see that having collections of varying size in a cell would turn large-scale searches into a nightmare. So for performance and simplicity, cells have one item of data. As a result, a lot of references have to either be in the children, or in a table made just for references.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to be able to add new things to the old without modifying them.

Suppose you have a client with names and addresses, then you add transactions. Transactions shouldn't modify the client. Then you add special orders for the client and so on. You shouldn't have to modify client table for all of those.

Code should work the same. This is a core principle of oop called coupling/cohesion

Comment: Well that starts to make sense for the databases. Thanks. But are you saying a class should not provide for references to child objects? ie: Instances of Class Person should not have a Limb references, but instances of Class Limb should reference the Person they are attached to?

Comment: Sql allows you to cheat a bit with some kind of global overseer that knows about all your objects. Person will probably need to interact with limb,  but a transaction may not need to know about it's customers. It really depends. Just minimize relationships as much as you can